# Can Flask remember and return additional context with the request routing?

Tags: python, flask

How to get Flask to pass some of my own context along with url context? I would like to set the context when the URL is provided e.g. via add_url_rule:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.add_url_rule('/myproj/one, view_func=myfuncone, 
                 methods=['GET'], context=mycontextone)
```

and I would like to access **mycontextone** when Flask calls **myfuncone()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curious - doesn't look like it's an option in flask as far as I can tell but you could wrap your view:

```
def myfuncone(id, **kwargs):
    print kwargs.keys()

import functools
myfuncone_with_context = functools.partial(myfuncone, context=mycontextone)
app.add_url_rule('/myproj/one', methods=['GET'],
                 view_func=myfuncone_with_context)
```